# Spring integration: process files line by line persisting read state

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to process files line by line using Spring integration file, which seems to be possible using `FileReadingMessageSource` and `FileSplitter`.

However, when the Spring integration application crashes or is restarted while processing a file, I do not want lines to get re-processed (at least not too many) or to get lost.

Is there a way to keep the read state of a file in Spring integration, so that processing is restarted where it left off? Does anyone has an example of such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to keep a read state in the `FileSplitter`, however I can suggest you to take a look into the `Idempotent Receiver` pattern. So, an endpoint which processes the line from the file could skip those already processed.

See more info in the Docs:https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#idempotent-receiver

Comment: That's a good suggestion - thank you! I implemented a custom advice similar to `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` (in particular, checking if the sequence number is greater than the last one processed, and updating the metadata store after processing, not before, to have at least once semantics), this works for me.

Comment: Good. See also an improvement we added to the `MetadataSelector`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/handler-advice.html#idempotent-receiver  - `BiPredicate compareValues`. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3241